# How to crop image on ScheduledTaskAgent in Windows Phone

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I need to crop an image using a ScheduledTaskAgent. Since it runs in the background I get a cross-thread exception when trying to instantiate a WriteableBitmap (as it needs to be created in the UI thread). I have a stream of the image, how would I go about cropping it without using a WriteableBitmap?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the dispatcher (and therefore the UI thread) even in a background agent:

```
protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
{
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        // Use the WriteableBitmap here

        this.NotifyComplete();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, after seeing this I saw the VS template even comes with Dispatcher.BeginInvoke in the constructor.

Comment: What about the memory limitation of the background agent? loading an image taken by the user goes past this memory limit