# Reading PNG, JPEGs in Background Agent

Tags: c#, image-processing, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to crop image on ScheduledTaskAgent in Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13657168/how-to-crop-image-on-scheduledtaskagent-in-windows-phone)

I'm trying to read and process (really, just resize) a PNG or a JPEG image in the background agent.

Turns out, I can't use BitmapImage or WriteableBitmap to make use of its PNG/JPEG decoding and resizing capabilities since they require running in the UI thread (which is obviously non-existent in the background agent).

I looked at third-party libraries, like ImageTools. ImageTools does not appear to support JPG for Windows Phone.

What can I do to be able to process (read, process, save) image while in the background thread? I obviously don't want to re-invent the wheel and write my own decoder.

Thank you,

Dan

P.S. Why are things always harder than you imagine they should be?

Answer (score 1):

I've been solving the exact same problem before, my solution is here:
[How to resize Image in C# WinRT/winmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349611/how-to-resize-image-in-c-sharp-winrt-winmd)