# create tile data in background agent wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, background-process, live-tile, writablebitmap

What's a good way to create the bitmap needed to update a live tile in a background agent? In the UI thread, you use writeableBitmap class, but this does not work in the non-ui thread. There are many examples of tiles in background agent, but they all use bitmaps formerly created in the UI. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: There are 3 ways a live tile can be customized. The text, a count in the top right or by changing the background image. Is the third what you want?

Answer (score 1):

> this does not work in the non-ui thread

WriteableBitmap doesn't need UI, it merely needs a Dispatcher. Background agents have it.

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13658385/126995) for sample.

Comment: Very slick solution. Thanks.